# Java - A TreeSet containing Lists of Integers?

Tags: java, list, sorting, set

I need a Set that contains a List of Integers. Each List contains 2 int values (for x and y coordinates) and I want to be able to implement some sort of compare method so that the Set is sorted depending on the first value (X value) for the List in ascending order so that Lists with the first value being very large will appear at the tail of the Set.

So that instead of printing out:

```
[2, 1]
[1, 2]
[3, 3]
[2, 3]
```

It prints out:

```
[1, 2] 
[2, 1]
[2, 3]
[3, 3]
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: 
java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

I honestly do not have much experience with sorting like this as I am a beginner. Any help would be brilliant, thanks!

Code so far:

```
public class Shape implements Comparator<List<Integer>> {
    private SortedSet<List<Integer>> coords;

    @Override
    public int compare(List<Integer> l1, List<Integer> l2) {
        if (l1.get(0) > l2.get(0))
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    public Shape(int shapeID) {
        coords = new TreeSet<List<Integer>>();        
        switch (shapeID) {
            case 1:
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(0, 2));
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(3, 2));
                break;
            case 2:
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(1, 1));
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(1, 2));
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(2, 1));
                break;
            case 3:
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(1, 3));
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(2, 1));
                coords.add(Arrays.asList(2, 3));
                break;            
        }
        coords.add(Arrays.asList(2, 2));
    }

    public void rotate() {
        Iterator<List<Integer>> it = coords.iterator();
        // should print out a sorted Set:
        while (it.hasNext()) {          
            System.out.println(it.next());
            // do more stuff here..
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Shape s = new Shape(2);
        s.rotate();

    }
}
```

Comment: If you only ever need two integers in the list you don't really need to use a list, prob. better to use a simple object containing to integers,.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two types of constructor for `TreeSets` - ones where you specify an explicit [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), and ones where you do not.  In the latter case, the set will use the *natural ordering* of its elements, which requires that they implement `Comparable`.  This is why you get the runtime exception, which is relatively clear (once you understand the background).

Since you can't make ArrayLists implement Comparable, you need to provide your own `Comparator` [when you're constructing the `TreeSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#TreeSet-java.util.Comparator-) to assign to `coords`.  This should be straightforward for you to implement (it's just a single function that takes two objects, and decides which one "comes first"), and you can put whatever custom ordering logic in there that you want.